# Is it possible to implement an abstract method that is not pure virtual in Pharo Smalltalk?

Tags: inheritance, methods, smalltalk, pharo

I know it is possible to implement a pure virtual method by using subclassResponsibility or a template method by calling a pure virtual method inside a concrete one. Now, it is possible to create a method with a default implementation but that **must** be implemented by subclasses? If yes, how (on Pharo)?

Example: suppose I want to provide a subclass of Collection that does some validation on #add but that do not implement the storage, thus leaving to its subclasses to decide what to do. While #add do have some implementation, it is still a subclass responsibility to finish it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, there in no really such thing as "abstract method" in Smalltalk. Key idea is that if you run that method, it sends `subclassResponsibility` to `self` and so the class signals you that this method is actually a responsibility of subclass in case you try to run it. Of course IDE can spot `subclassResponsibility` and mark method as "Abstract".

So I'd suggest you going with template i.e.

```
add: aThing
  (self validate: aThing)
    ifTrue: [ self store: aThing ]
    ifFalse: [ "signal error" ]
```

Where `store:` has `subclassResponsibility`

Comment: Yes, I know the term abstract and virtual do not apply to Smalltalk, but I thought it would be easier to explain myself using them since I don't know which terms are used in Smalltalk and since they are well known... But well, you got the idea. :)

Answer (score 3):

there is no such thing as a virtual method in Smalltalk. Or, to be more precise, all methods are "virtual".

the problem you are trying to solve needs to be solved this way:

```
add: anObject 
  self someValidationOf: anObject.
  self basicAdd: anObject.

basicAdd: anObject
  self subclassResponsibility.
```

Pretty simple :)

And honestly, I don't know how you would that differently, no matter the language (any OO language I can think of has to do this in the same way).

Comment: Yes, that is the way in others OO languages as well... I was just wondering if that was possible in Smalltalk. Maybe it is silly, but just occurred to me :)

Comment: @VitorCruz well… Smalltalk is super flexible, and now pharo has Opal compiler, so you can try to introduce something like that and see if it works